# How to enforce Java 1.6 standard during compilation in Ant?

Tags: java, ant, java-7, java-6

I use JDK 7. But, there is a class I want to compile to Java 6 standard (means, it must be able to run on JRE 6). My Ant compilation command is as following:

```
<target name="myAntTarget">
        <javac srcdir="${mysrc.dir}"
            destdir="${mydest.dir}"
            source="1.6"
            target="1.6"
            deprecation="on"
            debug="on"
            classpathref="mypath"
            includeAntRuntime="false"
        >
            <include name="com/mypackage/MyClassName.java" />
        </javac>        
</target>
```

Strangely, the Java 6 standard is not consistently enforced.

When I wrote

```
ProcessBuilder.Redirect xxx = ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT;
System.out.println(xxx.toString());
```

The code is successfully compiled (unexpected), even though ProcessBuilder.Redirect has been included in Java only since Java 7 (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.Redirect.html). So certainly it can't run properly in Java 6.

However, when I wrote

```
try (BufferedReader br =
        new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:/myrandomfile.pdf"))) {
    final String sss = br.readLine();
    System.out.println(sss);
}
```

The code fails to compile. The error message (from Ant) is

```
error: try-with-resources is not supported in -source 1.6
```

This time, the compiler can detect the problem.

How to ensure that Ant consistently fails to compile (and throw appropriate error message) whenever the java file it compiles is not Java 6 compatible?

Comment: fajrian, if your using Eclipse, check the compiler level for the project. There is your IDE's view of your project and there is what your built tool (ANT, Maven, IVY etc) sees. Also make sure you clean the projects.

Comment: @DesolatePlanet: The compilation is done from the command line

Comment: The problem is that `source` and `target` only modify the *language level* use and don't modify which libraries are used! In fact the Java 7 "platform" doesn't "know" which classes/fields where available in Java 6.

Comment: @JoachimSauer: I tried to do similar thing using javac command (javac -source 1.6 -target 1.6 MyClassName.java), and apparently the result is the same (ProcessBuilder.Redirect is compilable to Java 6, but try-with-resources is uncompilable to Java 6). So probably it's not exactly Ant's fault. Is there any workaround to ensure that the compiled class is Java 6 compatible?

Comment: @fajrian: right, it's not ants fault ... you *can* define which library to compile against (keyword: `bootclasspath`), but that means you need to have a 1.6 JDK or JRE installed. And at that point you can usually just compile directly with the 1.6 JDK.

Comment: @JoachimSauer: It seems that the only way here is compiling using JDK 6 then. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `source` attribute enforces source code level compliance. By assigning `source=1.6`, you ask the compiler to ensure that the source code, from a *syntax* point of view, is compatible with the Java 1.6 specification.

The `target` attribute to value `X` tells the compiler to generate `class` files that will be readable by JVMs of level that is *at least* `X`. By assigning `target=1.6`, you ask the compiler to generate classes that will only be readable by JVMs of level 1.6 onwards.

Neither of these parameters dictate to the compiler which JDK libraries to use as compile-time dependencies. If you want to ensure that your code can run on a Java 1.6 JVM, then you must use the `javac` compiler included with Java 1.6. Also, you're likely to either omit the `target` parameter altogether, or to keep it - but if you keep it, ensure that it is, indeed, set to `1.6`.